# how do i convert ["'c'", "'d'", "'a'", "'b'"] into ['c','d','a','b']?? "" is a string type

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

how do I convert `["'c'", "'d'", "'a'", "'b'"]` into `['c','d','a','b']`
"" is a string type

Comment: Please show us what you tried

Comment: `[x.replace("'","") for x in your_list]` I used the `replace` method and comprehension list

Answer (score 3):

You could use [string slicing](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) to remove the first and last character from a string:

```
l = ["'c'", "'d'", "'a'", "'b'"]
new = [x[1:-1] for x in l]
print(new)
```

Out:

```
['c', 'd', 'a', 'b']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `" ' "`(quotes)  with `""` (blanks)

```
arr = ["'c'", "'d'", "'a'", "'b'"]
new_arr = [ele.replace("'","") for ele in arr ]
```

Out

```
['c', 'd', 'a', 'b']
```